How can I get correct co-ordinates for tracking phone number using Python and folium
I have been trying the following code but the coordinates in the output given in the terminal are wrong.
Neither the SIM information is correct nor the co-ordinates. Other than that the city name is also not visible.
import phonenumbers  
from phonenumbers import geocoder  
from phonenumbers import carrier  
import opencage  
from opencage.geocoder import OpenCageGeocode  
import folium  


key = "My key" #Geocoder API Key 
number = input("please giver your number: ")
new_number = phonenumbers.parse(number)
location = geocoder.description_for_number(new_number, "en")
print(location)

service_name = carrier.name_for_number(new_number,"en")
print(service_name)

geocoder = OpenCageGeocode(key)
query = str(location)
result = geocoder.geocode(query)
print(result)

lat = result[0]['geometry']['lat']
lng = result[0]['geometry']['lng']`

print(lat, lng)

my_map = folium.Map(location=[lat,lng], zoom_start=9)
folium.Marker([lat, lng], popup= location).add_to(my_map)

my_map.save("location.html")

print("location tracking completed")
print("Thank you")


What inputs do you use? what is the expected output vs the actual output?

I give my phone number as input and the output gives the country name, sim card company and co-ordinates. However the sim card company is wrong plus if I look at the coordinates on map, it shows a completely different location . (for example, Gujarat instead of Rajasthan).
